# How can I make this recursive function generate all permutations of a tic tac toe game?

Tags: javascript, recursion, minimax

I'm trying to write a minimax algorithim for a tic tac toe game. I created a recursive function that is supposed to iterate through the available spaces in an array of the board, changing them to get all possible outcomes, and weight any final board states with a score. It creates an infinite loop right now. Am I close to doing this right?

Here's what I have:

```
  //boardstate updated with 1's for human choice 2's for cpu, representative of a tic tac toe board 
  var boardState = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

    //gets index of best move playerNum === 1 = human turn, 2 = cpu turn
function minMax (newBoard, playerNum) {
  var openSpaces = getOpenSpaces(newBoard);

  //checks for win condition gives score of -10 if human win 10 if cpu win 0 if stalemate
  if (checkWinState(newBoard, 1)){
    return -10;
  } else if (checkWinState(newBoard, 2)){
    return 10;
  } else if (openSpaces.length === 0){
    return 0;
  }

  var moves = [];

  //iterates through board array changing values to get all possible outcomes
  for (var i = 0; i < openSpaces.length; i++){
    var move = {};
    move.index = openSpaces[i];

    newBoard[openSpaces[i]] = playerNum;

    if(playerNum === 1){
      var result = minMax(newBoard, 2);
      move.score = result;
    } else if(playerNum === 2){
      var result = minMax(newBoard, 1);
      move.score = result;
    }

    newBoard[openSpaces[i]] = 0;

    moves.push(move);
  }

  var bestMove;
  if (playerNum === 2){
    var bestScore = -1000;
    for(var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++){
      if (moves[i].score > bestScore){
        bestScore = moves[i].score;
        bestMove = i;
      }
    }
  } else {
    var bestScore = 1000;
    for (var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++){
      if(moves[i].score < bestScore){
        bestScore = moves[i].score;
        bestMove = i;
      }
    }
  }
  return bestMove;
}

//gets index of open spaces
function getOpenSpaces(board){
 var openSpaceIndexes = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
   if (board[i] === 0){
     openSpaceIndexes.push(i);
   }
 }
 return openSpaceIndexes;
}
```

Comment: Eventhough you do make an attempt at writing a recursion function, there's no demonstration that you understand `minimax` at all. Where is the calculation of all possible outcomes for your move, and choosing the "maximum" score. a calculation of all possible outcomes for your opponent, and choosing the "minimum" score. What is the definition of your minimax heuristic function. How do you intend to compare / combine scores? None of these things are defined and are clear in you pseudo code.

Comment: There's also a built-in performance problem, since, your algorithm does attempt to "play" the entire game from the starting point. It would better if you try to play a game from an arbitrary board position. i.e. what is my next "best" move. If I do a lookahead = 1, it will just rank all my possible moves and pick "max", if I do a lookahead = 2, it will rank all my possible moves "max" against all possible counter attacks from the opponent "min". I think if you start with lookahead = 1 or 2 scenarios and get it right, then, you can think about generalizing it to lookahead = n.

Comment: I thought calling the function recursively and having newBoard[openSpaces[i]] = playerNum; was doing something with permutations. I'm pretty green, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing. Guess it's back to the drawing board. Thanks.

Comment: Try following one recursion all the way to end game on paper.  Does it stop correctly at win or tie, and return the right result?